# Caterpillar identification

Tags: species-identification, entomology, lepidoptera

It has since cocooned I think but it was a weird circumstance. I kept adding leaves for it to eat, and it decided it was done, and cocooned under a wilted leaf.  I'm wondering if anyone can ID the species, and the following: I think it is a real cocoon, as there is no dead or rot smell.

But the cocoon was under the wilted leaf, and is now quite firmly attached. In the pics below, I've turned the leaf and cocoon over. Does the cocoon know "up"? And does it know it before or after making the cocoon? If it was stuck on its "up and out" direction, can turing it over be harmful? I.e. I turned it over so now it's trying to emerge towards the ground, can it figure out how to find 'up'?

Locale: Southwestern United States
Found in: found it in a moist garden bed (tomatoes, radishes, peppermint, basil) eating radish leaves
Description: About 2 inches long, 1/2 inch long hairy, black/grey hairs, body is black/grey with yellow striped markings

Cocooning position: wilted leaf / \, stick |, cocoon (), ...

```
 /|\
/()|\
```

Summary: It made the cocoon with the leaf on top of it, and it would never make it out in that case, so I turned it over. Is that okay? Can we still see the winged form come out? Like I said, it doesn't smell dead... in fact smells better than when the caterpillar was pooping everywhere.

Aside, this is the only tag I could find that might fit. Please feel free to edit tags to get this answered. TY

Caterpillar
[image: the caterpillar]

Cocoon after being turned over, you can see it's kind of wrapped in the leaf
[image]

Comment: Till you put your pics, can we keep this question on hold? Because your textual information is also insufficient. Describe the caterpillar: colour, size texture etc. Describe your geographic location and local landscape.

Comment: @WYSIWYG added images and more description

Comment: From an unrelated [answer](http://biology.stackexchange.com/a/9115/14894), I think it might be a [saltmarsh caterpillar](http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/veg/leaf/saltmarsh_caterpillar.htm). Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: This question is still open probably because the quality of the image is not good. Why don't you take it outside the jar for making picture? Like this it could be anything.

Comment: @ruffp because it's been over a year since I had the caterpillar, and I confirmed a few days after posting that it was, indeed, dead. I should probably just delete the question

Answer (score 2):

Although a definitive ID will likely never be possible with such low quality photos, you probably have a **Western Tent Caterpillar** (*Malacosoma californicum*).

[image: http://www.butterfliesandmoths.org/sites/default/files/voucher_images/yell12d2519xa.jpg]

[image: http://bugguide.net/images/raw/QZT/L0Z/QZTL0ZALKZCL7Z9LLZPLLZ3ZLZELKZELLZOZYL1LPRHH2RALMZLHSZQHER1LMZCLPRDLMZBL2RSH5R.jpg]

According to the [USDA Forest Service](https://www.fs.usda.gov/Internet/FSE_DOCUMENTS/stelprdb5303047.pdf), mature larvae are about **2 inches (4.5-5.1 cm) long** and are **highly variable in color and markings**.

- This insect is the most variable of the North American species of *Malacosoma*, in which six subspecies and several unclassified forms have been recognized.

Although this species eats primarilly trees and shrubs (e.g., see [here](https://www.fs.usda.gov/Internet/FSE_DOCUMENTS/stelprdb5303047.pdf) and [here](https://pace.oregonstate.edu/courses/sites/default/files/resources/pdf/fsbdev2_042847.pdf)), the [Minnesota DNR](http://www.dnr.state.mn.us/treecare/forest_health/ftc/homeownertips.html) suggests that garden plants can also be targeted.

Cocoons are of white silk dusted with a white to yellow powder. Your image appears to show that.

The Western Caterpillar is found throughout western North America:

[image: western tent caterpillar range]

<sup>[Source: [USDA Forest Service](https://pace.oregonstate.edu/courses/sites/default/files/resources/pdf/fsbdev2_042847.pdf)]</sup>